# GIS software for shading drawn polygons based on data?

Tags: google-maps, ms-office, gis, arcgis

I am looking for a program that allows me to draw (preferably import...) tracks or polygons to overlay on a map. A table in the program is then filled with data, similar to below:

```
Zone  |  Value
--------------
A     |  90%
B     |  50%
C     |  25%
```

etc.

The area of the polygons or tracks is then shaded a designated color, with the opacity based on the values in this table. As the values are changed, the map is automatically updated.

Anyone have any ideas on what programs are capable of this?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By using QGIS, it is possible, in styles, you can define styles "rule based" of colors by values from a field in table.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Franklin QGIS would be a good choice. However, I would use the 'Data Defined Override' ability in the Styles tab of the layer Properties window.  This gives you the option to either:
a) use a column in the attribute table to define colour/opacity/...anything really, but you'll have to add additional style columns to your attribute table.
b) write a CASE WHEN expression (which I think closer fits your need).  If your new to QGIS then you would write your expression like this.

```
CASE
WHEN "Zone" = 'A' THEN rgb(255,0,0)
WHEN "Zone" = 'B' ...
END
```

That rgb code creates a red fill colour for zone A.
You can use the same expression for opacity, instead of the 'rgb()' at the end of the code just have an integer value for the level of transparency eg.

```
WHEN "Value" = '90%' THEN 50
```

quick question, are the values in your 'Value' column a string or integer (you've written them with % in your example)? no big problem because if they are integers then you can drop the single quotes.